# What does the class "is-upgraded" in material-design-lite do and how is it set?

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm implementing Material Design with Material-Design-lite in a React app. When I'm using TextField w/Floating Label within my top component, it works. But on a component called by by top component, it doesn't. TextField w/Floating Label then acts a regular input field.

I noticed that outer TextField gets a class named "is-upgraded", but inner TextField doesn't.

app structure

```
app.js
  products.js
    myTest.js (doesn't work)
  myTest.js (works)
```

App.jsx

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Products/>
        <MyTest id="products" type="text"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Products.jsx

```
export default class Products extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <List items={this.state.products}/>
        <MyTest id="products" type="text"/>
        <AddProduct/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

myTest.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default class MyTest extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="mdl-textfield
                        mdl-js-textfield
                        mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input
            className="mdl-textfield__input"
            id={this.props.id}
            type={this.props.type}/>
          <label
            className="mdl-textfield__label"
            htmlFor={this.props.id}>
            Test
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
   }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <base href="/">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script    src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MDL enhances normal DOM elements by *upgrading* them to MDL components. In case of non-dynamic elements (i.e. everything that is already in DOM tree upon `window.load`), MDL automatically upgrades them upon `window.load` to MDL components. For everything else [you have to use](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic) `componentHandler` to upgrade your elements manually. There as an [article here](http://quaintous.com/2015/07/09/react-components-with-mdl/) which explains how to integrate React with MDL:

> Integrating MDL with React is as easy as calling a single method:
>   `componentHandler.upgradeDom();`. In my opinion, the best place to put
>   this code is in the `componentDidUpdate` callback, which is invoked just
>   after and element has been updated and successfully rendered. This way
>   we can make sure that our React component already exists in the DOM
>   and can be upgraded by the `componentHandler`.

So you would have something like this:

```js
var TestButton = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button ref="submit" className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        Submit
      </button>
    );
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    // This upgrades all upgradable components (i.e. with 'mdl-js-*' class)
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();

    // We could have done this manually for each component
    /*
     * var submitButton = this.refs.submit.getDOMNode();
     * componentHandler.upgradeElement(submitButton, "MaterialButton");
     * componentHandler.upgradeElement(submitButton, "MaterialRipple");
     */
  }
});
```

*Disclaimer*: I am the author of the aforementioned article!

Comment: Thank you. This is a great article that explains how MDL is implemented with React.

Comment: @user3846507 you are very welcome :) I am really glad that the article could be helpful!